Getting 'Element not defined' Error for ExtGraphNodes in OPL model
I'm working on an optimization problem using IBM's OPL (Optimization Programming Language). I have defined a set called ExtGraphNodes in my model file, but when I try to use it in my data file, I encounter an error stating that the element is not defined.
I have declared the set as follows in my model file:
{TimedNode} ExtGraphNodes;
In my data file, I define the set using:
ExtGraphNodes = { <"A1", 0>, <"A1", 1>, ... };
However, I still receive an error saying "Element 'ExtGraphNodes' not defined." I expected that with the correct declaration, the model should recognize the set.
my code

You must declare your set as follows in your model file:
{TimedNode} ExtGraphNodes = ...;

See the doc about Initializing sets.
I hope this helps.
Chris.
